# CMake on Linux CentOS 7, how to force the system to use cmake3?

Tags: python-2.7, cmake, centos, centos7, pytorch

I tried to install [PyTorch](http://pytorch.org) on my Linux CentOS 7.3. I downloaded its package, ran this command and got this error:

```
sudo python setup.py install

running install
running build_deps
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:1 (cmake_minimum_required):
  CMake 3.0 or higher is required.  You are running version 2.8.12.2


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

So I tried to install CMake 3 by using the command

```
sudo yum -y install cmake3
```

The installation went alright, but the system still uses cmake2.8 as default.
If I type the yum info comnmand, I get this:

```
sudo yum info cmake

Installed Packages
Name        : cmake
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 2.8.12.2
Release     : 2.el7
Size        : 27 M
Repo        : installed
From repo   : base
Summary     : Cross-platform make system
URL         : http://www.cmake.org
License     : BSD and MIT and zlib
Description : CMake is used to control the software compilation process using simple
            : platform and compiler independent configuration files. CMake generates
            : native makefiles and workspaces that can be used in the compiler
            : environment of your choice. CMake is quite sophisticated: it is possible
            : to support complex environments requiring system configuration, preprocessor
            : generation, code generation, and template instantiation.
```

So, the problem is clear: **the system still sees cmake2.8 as default, and therefore Python does not use cmake3 for its PyTorch installation.**
How can I solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 68):

Once you have both the `cmake` and the `cmake3` package installed on your machine, you can use [update-alternatives](https://linux.die.net/man/8/update-alternatives) to switch between both packages.

Use the `alternatives` command to register both installations:

```
$ sudo alternatives --install /usr/local/bin/cmake cmake /usr/bin/cmake 10 \
--slave /usr/local/bin/ctest ctest /usr/bin/ctest \
--slave /usr/local/bin/cpack cpack /usr/bin/cpack \
--slave /usr/local/bin/ccmake ccmake /usr/bin/ccmake \
--family cmake

$ sudo alternatives --install /usr/local/bin/cmake cmake /usr/bin/cmake3 20 \
--slave /usr/local/bin/ctest ctest /usr/bin/ctest3 \
--slave /usr/local/bin/cpack cpack /usr/bin/cpack3 \
--slave /usr/local/bin/ccmake ccmake /usr/bin/ccmake3 \
--family cmake
```

After these two commands, `cmake3` will be invoked by default, when you enter `cmake` from a bash prompt or start a bash script. The commands also take care of registering a few secondary commands like `ctest` which need to be switched along with `cmake`.

If you need to switch back to cmake 2.8 as the default, run the following command:

```
$ sudo alternatives --config cmake

There are 2 programs which provide 'cmake'.

  Selection    Command
-----------------------------------------------
   1           cmake (/usr/bin/cmake)
*+ 2           cmake (/usr/bin/cmake3)

Enter to keep the current selection[+], or type selection number: 1
```

Comment: It is not working for me. /usr/local/bin/cmake is calling cmake3 but I would like /usr/bin/cmake to call cmake3. Is it possible ?

Comment: you should make sure /usr/local/bin is earlier in your path: :/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin

Answer (score 16):

Creating this symbolic link after installing cmake3 on Centos 7 worked for me:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/cmake3 /usr/bin/cmake
```

Answer (score 9):

In case you don't have root access, just create a link like this (as ~/bin is typically in your PATH):

```
ln -s /usr/bin/cmake3 ~/bin/cmake
```

Comment: in some spec for example libzip.spec it works :

    mkdir ~/bin
    export PATH=~/bin:$PATH
    ln -s /usr/bin/cmake3 ~/bin/cmake

Answer (score 1):

On Centos, package `cmake3` [contains](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/epel-x86_64/cmake3-3.6.3-1.el7.x86_64.rpm.html) an executable named `cmake3`. Because most programs execute `cmake`, they don't find cmake3.

As usual, you may somewhere create a link named `cmake` which points to `/usr/bin/cmake3` and place directory to this link in the *PATH* variable before other directories.

Comment: Thanks, how do you do that in the ~/.bashrc file?

Comment: `export PATH=<your-dir>:$PATH` may work. But you run `python setup.py install` via `sudo`, so you should modify root environment, not an environment for your user. For use cmake3 once you better pass variable to sudo: `sudo PATH=<your-dir>:$PATH python setup.py install`.

Comment: I've just executed "sudo ln -s /usr/bin/cmake3 /usr/bin/cmake"

Comment: That's a bad idea to mess with system files. It will be overwritten when the cmake package is updated. In addition other software which expects the presence of cmake V. 2 in /usr/bin/cmake may not appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

in some spec for example libzip.spec it works :

```
BuildRequires:  cmake3

mkdir ~/bin
export PATH=~/bin:$PATH
ln -s /usr/bin/cmake3 ~/bin/cmake
```